# Bash script operand expected

Tags: bash, unix, math

I'm having a small problem with this following snippet and I'm not sure why. The error given is (line indicated):

*2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*2")

```
while [[ $numberServers -gt $newindex ]]; do
    serverPort=$((9001+$(($newindex*2))))      <--- This line
    clientPort=$(($serverPort+1))
    newindex=$(($newindex+1))
    localhostport=$((serverPort-2))

    string=$(($string,localhost:$(($serverPort-2))))
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like `$newindex` didn't have the value you were expecting. What value does it have?

Comment: It does look as if `$newindex` is empty. You should probably test that it has a value before you use it in a formula. Also, too many parentheses!  `serverPort=$((9001+$newindex*2))` should do exactly the same thing. Similarly, `newindex=$(($newindex+1))` can be replaced with `((newindex++))`.

Comment: You're also misusing arithmetic expressions in the last line; presumably, you want to append the string `localhost:$(($serverPort-2))` to the end of `string`.

Comment: @chepner How do you mean? I am now getting an error on that line so I agree, I just can't see how/where I am misusing the arithmetic?

Comment: I assume you want `string="$string,localhost:$localhostport"` or `string+=",locahost:$localhostport"`. At best, `$(($string,localhost:$locahostport))` would evaluate `$string`, discard the result, and evaluate to the next string. But arithmetic expressions are for just that: *arithmetic*, not string handling. Neither argument of the `,` operator is an arithmetic expression.

Comment: @chepner Ok, so just to clarify, I need to assign the arithmetic expression to a variable and then concatenate that? Also, the form I want this loop to achieve is: localhost:9001,localhost:9003.... So I want to add the commas during concatenation too.

Comment: Techinically, you don't need the temporary variable, if it is indeed temporary and you don't use it again. E.g., `string+=",localhost:$((serverPort - 2))"` is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `newindex` is empty, so the expression became:

```
$((9001+$((*2))))
```

check the initialization of `newindex`.

**Example:**

```
$ echo $((9001+$(($newindex*2))))
bash: *2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*2")

$ newindex=4

$ echo $((9001+$(($newindex*2))))
9009
```

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistake really. But now I'm getting another error? line 26: ,localhost:9001: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ",localhost:9001")

Comment: @CAFC_Sam no problem..that seems like an syntax error..hard to tell without seeing the problematic line i.e. line 26..

Comment: line 26 is just
        string=$(($string,localhost:$(($serverPort-2))))

Comment: @CAFC_Sam now `string` is empty..also its unclear to me what you are doing here ..

Comment: I have initialised `string`. I'm trying to just loop through a set of port numbers and add them all to the end of string, ready for a command line argument to a Java program

Comment: @CAFC_Sam i would suggest you to ask that as a new question explaining what you are trying to do and whats you have done so far..also please select it as accepted as this solved your initial query..